# Why doesn't my navigation bar hide on swipe?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to get my navigation bar to hide when I swipe up and reappear when I swipe down. I print function works but I'm not sure why my navigation bar doesn't hide. Also how do I get the part on top which is an image and a logo to hide on swipe.
[image]

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

    if(velocity.y>0) {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(), animations: {
            self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)


            print("Hide")
        }, completion: nil)

    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(), animations: {
            self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)

            print("Unhide")
        }, completion: nil)    
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure self.navigationController is not nil. If it is nil that code will fail silently.

Comment: where do i check that? @DuncanC

Comment: Change your print statement to read `print("About to hide. navigationController = \(self.navigationController)")`

Answer (score 0):

Your can try to hide nav bar in this way

```
navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
```

This will automatically hide the bar when you scroll up, and show the bar when you scroll down. It will also handle the resize and animation.

One problem with your code is that `scrollViewWillEndDragging` is not triggered until you finished dragging, and may be triggered multiple times in one drag action